# Calculating GetHashCode efficiently with unordered list

Tags: c#, linq

I'm wondering what would be the best way to calculate the hashcode when the order of a sequence doesn't matter. Here's the custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` i've implemented for an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19089162/284240) on Stackoverflow.

```
public class AccDocumentItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<AccDocumentItem>
{
    public bool Equals(AccDocumentItem x, AccDocumentItem y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;
        if (x.AccountId != y.AccountId)
            return false;
        return x.DocumentItemDetails.Select(d => d.DetailAccountId).OrderBy(i => i)
            .SequenceEqual(y.DocumentItemDetails.Select(d => d.DetailAccountId).OrderBy(i => i));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(AccDocumentItem obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return int.MinValue;
        int hash = obj.AccountId.GetHashCode();
        if (obj.DocumentItemDetails == null)
            return hash;
        int detailHash = 0;
        unchecked
        {
            var orderedDetailIds =  obj.DocumentItemDetails
                .Select(d => d.DetailAccountId).OrderBy(i => i);
            foreach (int detID in orderedDetailIds)
                detailHash = 17 * detailHash + detID;
        }
        return hash + detailHash;
    }  
}
```

As you can see the `foreach` in `GetHashCode` needs to order the (nested) sequence before it starts calculating the hashcode. If the sequence is large this seems to be inefficient. Is there a better way to calculate the hashcode if the  order of a sequence can be ignored?

Here are the simple classes involved:

```
public class AccDocumentItem
{
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public List<AccDocumentItemDetail> DocumentItemDetails { get; set; }
}


public class AccDocumentItemDetail
{
    public int LevelId { get; set; }
    public int DetailAccountId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply assign a unique ID upon creation of an object and redefine 'equality' of two objects instead? Using the ID when the `GetHashCode` is called is efficient and in case you have to compare two objects for equal content, you can use your redefined 'Equals'  method.

Comment: @alzaimar I think that most of the time, when you want some kind of value equality, you can't just use reference equality instead. For example, this could be used to detect changes in the object, but your solution wouldn't work for that.

Comment: Correct, but if I want to detect changes, I would maintain a 'Modified' property instead of trying to find changes. If I want to compare two instances whether they contain the same data, I would write a method doing that etc. But I would *never* use 'GetHashCode' to detect changes.

Comment: @alzaimar: I'm not sure if i've understood your suggestion. Of course using an `ID` is efficient. But the whole point of creating a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` is to use it for the linq extension methods like `GroupBy`. And the requirement was to differentiate `ParentClass` objets with the `AccountId` **and** the nested `List<DetailClass>` and their `DetailAccountId`. So if the `AccountId` is equal **and all** of the `DetailAccountId`s(independent of the order), then both objects are equal.

Comment: Got it. Use any hash you like (addition, xor) and don't forget to fully compare if the hashes match, as they always is a chance for collisions.

Comment: The simplest solution is to get hashes of individual items and order them. You can then use any operation to calculate the resulting hash and the item order won't matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the order does not matter, use an kommutative operator to combine the hashCodes of the elements.

Possible candidates are:
`^` binary `xor`   // *THIS WOULD BE MY CHOICE*
`+` addition       // problem may be the overflow
`*` multiplication         // problem may be the overflow
`|` binary `or`    // not recommended, because after some of this operations it is likely that all bits are set, so the same hashCode would appear for quite different instances)

Comment: Thanks. However, Mr Skeet himself advise againt using `xor`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/284240 The `sum` approach is problematic since `1 + 1` would be the same as `2`.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: You will never be able to avoid the possibility of collisions. And it is also not necessary to try to. Only try to avoid too many collisions because it would decrease performance of e.g. HashHmap. But feel free to multiply the hashCode of each element by the same constant before applying the kommutative operator It will change nothing `17*1 + 17*1 == 17*2`.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: If you want the `order of a sequence doesn't matter` feature, I cannot imagen an implementation not using an `kommutative operator`.

Comment: I don't want to avoid the possibility of collision entirely, but as  good as (so it's fine to overflow with the possibility of collisions).  The resulting distribution of the additive and multiplicative hashes and even the `xor` are just not good enough. But that's probably better than ordering the sequence first (so +1).

Comment: @TimSchmelter And half of the reason Skeet advises against XOR is because it's commutative. Normally, you don't want hash(x,y)==hash(y,x), but that's exactly what you're asking for. (The other half of his point still stands, though.)

Comment: @svick: You can avoid the other one `hashCode(x,x) == 0 == hash(y,y)` by using `+` or `*`.

Comment: @MrSmith42 `*` has a different (and possibly even worse) flaw: 0 * anything == 0. That's not hard to work around, but I think it's worth mentioning.

Comment: @svick: You could use `(x+4)*(y+4)*...` to avoid the `0` problem. Or simply add a condition and replace every `0` by any other constant.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I think the first solution wouldn't work: what if `x` was -4? But yeah, something like `x == 0 ? 1 : x` would work.

Comment: @svick: All the attemps would work, a `0` in the product would only result in a very likely collision and therefore in bad HashSet performance, but it would still work.

Comment: @MrSmith42: My question was not about _working_ approaches ( have already one) but to find the most efficient that produces as less as possible collisions. However, i assume that this is a case where  collisions are unavoidable.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: There is no solution with 'as less as possible collisions'. There will always be collisions and if you know nothing about the hashCodes of the elements you cannot avoid the possibility that there are only collisions. If you know something about the distribution of the hashCodes of the single elements or come characteristics they have, you might be able to use this knowledge to reduce collisions. You may implement some variations and profile how many collisions you get for your test data.

Comment: @MrSmith42, could you please update the answer so it suggests "combine the results from multiple commutative hash functions"?
For instance: compute xor (a), compute sum (b), compute product (c) of the input elements, then use (a*17+b)*17+c as the overall hash function for the unordered list. It is easy to implement, and it would avoid pitfalls of individual xor/sum/product hashes.